# In React, add styles to inner input in InputNumber from rc-input-number library

Tags: reactjs, input

`https://input-number.vercel.app/` - nested inside of a react `<InputNumber />` is an `input` with class `rc-input-number-input`. Is it possible to update the styles on this inner `input`? The InputNumber component has a `style` prop but that seems to only style the outer `rc-input-number` div.

[image]

Comment: I am able to add a className to the component, and then add styles to the `rc-input-number-input` via the class in our CSS file.